# Performing multiple mysql queries in one call

Tags: mysql

I would like to understand how to retrieve multiple mysql values in one call. As is, I have the current query, which works.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
        (3595 * 
            acos(
                cos(radians({$lat1}))
                * cos(radians(lattitude))
                * cos(radians(longitude) - radians({$lon1}))
                + sin(radians({$lat1}))
                * sin(radians(lattitude))
            )
        ) AS distance
        FROM members WHERE person = 'single'
        HAVING distance < 50
    );
```

This is later called by my PHP like so:

```
$single = $row['cnt'];

echo json_encode( array(
    'single' => $single
) );
```

My hypothetical table is comprised of people who are `single`, `married`, and `divorced`. In this example I have only performed a query for people who are `single`. I would like to know how I might modify my query so as to perform the same request for all these groups using the same mySQl query. Particularly using the `json encode` function.

One example I have seen relies upon multiple separate `SELECT` statements, combined with multiple instances of `$row['cnt']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version, very similar to @scaisEdge's. Actually, if there are no more categories than `single`, `married` and `divorced`, the `WHERE` clause is not needed.

```
$conn = new mysqli( $host, $user, $pass, $db );

$result = $conn->query( "
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
        (3595 * 
            acos(
                cos(radians({$lat1}))
                * cos(radians(lattitude))
                * cos(radians(longitude) - radians({$lon1}))
                + sin(radians({$lat1}))
                * sin(radians(lattitude))
            )
        ) AS distance,
        person -- <-- this gives you the category in the result
    FROM
        members 
    WHERE
        person in ('single', 'divorced', 'married')
    GROUP BY
        person
    HAVING
        distance < 50
" );

$rows =  $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

echo json_encode( $rows );
```

*mysqli_result::fetch_all* can help you to get what you need. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php ;)

**Update:**

What I'd do in JS is something similar to this:

```
data.forEach( function( item )
{
    switch ( item.person )
    {
        case 'single':
            $( "#count_single" ).html( item.cnt )
            break

        case 'married':
            $( "#count_married" ).html( item.cnt )
            break

        case 'divorced':
            $( "#count_divorced" ).html( item.cnt )
            break
    }
} )
```

Comment: This gives me a JSON result that looks something like `[{"cnt":"1","person":"single"}]` which is really cool, but I am still not certain how to separate the info on my AJAX call so as to do something like `$('#div').html(data.marriednumbercount)`

Comment: Oooooh. I get it. It would be something like `$("#count_married").html(data[0].cnt);` and so forth. Thx!

Comment: You can always transform the result a bit at MySQL or PHP level to get the structure as you needed in JSON. But I updated the answer to add a js snippet of how I'd do it with that MySQL outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could use group by

```
SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
        (3595 * 
            acos(
                cos(radians({$lat1}))
                * cos(radians(lattitude))
                * cos(radians(longitude) - radians({$lon1}))
                + sin(radians({$lat1}))
                * sin(radians(lattitude))
            )
        ) AS distance
        FROM members 
        GROUP By person
        HAVING distance < 50
    );
```

In this way you get a row for each person value

Comment: So how might I query `$row['cnt']` from each individual (single, married, divorced)?